# I need to put in a scrollview an unknown number of images and I don't know how

Tags: android, scrollview

I searched so long and didn't find what I need.
Basically I want to make a vertical scrollview in my activity that will show images and to each image there would be a description of the image and the name of it.

The problem is that the number of the images is different each time the user opens the activity(it depends on his choice in the activity before).

Can you please help figure out how to make it work?

Comment: There are multiple possibilities 
ListView 
GridView 
RecycleView 
CardView 
all you need is choose which suits you according to your scenario

Comment: you can try logic. like when user come on that activity in that onResume() method you can make on dialog box which have edittext or Spinner which form which you get number of imageView user want. then what ever number you get from user you can setvisibility of image view of your layout rest image view visibility by default you can set Gone

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [GridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) documentation for this.

Also you can check  an implementation of GridView in [this](http://javatechig.com/android/android-gridview-example-building-image-gallery-in-android) post.

`CardView` can also be implemented in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 0):

You should add **ImageView** at **runtime**. 
Add **LinearLayout** to **ScrollView**.
When user enters activity add **ImageView** to **LinearLayout** as much as you want.
If you don't know the number of image, this is the best way I think.